# Dynamic bounding box for Mapbox Geocoder

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to apply Mapbox Geocoder (Mapbox GL JS) search limit depending on currently visible map bounds. Current code output an error upon search attempts ("uncaught exception: Object"):

```
   map.on('zoom', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    geocoder.options.bbox = [bounds.getNorthEast().lng, bounds.getNorthEast().lat, bounds.getSouthWest().lng, bounds.getSouthWest().lat];
   });
```

Is this possible at all? If so - how to correct the code?

edit:

Solved. It turned out bbox parameter has tricky order (especially for UK with both negative and positive longitudes presented) from min to max values instead of LonLatBounds order (NE to SW). If anyone interesting - correctly working code would be

```
// notice switch from 'zoom' to 'move'
map.on('move', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    var minLon = bounds.getNorthEast().lng;
    var maxLon = bounds.getSouthWest().lng;
    if(minLon > maxLon) {
        maxLon = minLon;
        var minLon = bounds.getSouthWest().lng;
    }
    var minLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat;
    var maxLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat;
    if(minLat > maxLat) {
        maxLat = minLat;
        var minLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat;
    }
    if(minLon >= -180 && maxLon <= 180) geocoder.options.bbox = [minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat];
});
```

edit 2: somehow .flat() from the selected reply malfunction in MS Edge. Be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the API documentation https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#setbbox the correct way is to call

```
geocoder.setBbox([minX, minY, maxX, maxY]);
```

`map.getBounds().toArray()` returns `[sw, ne]` so you should be able to do:

```
geocoder.setBbox(map.getBounds().toArray().flat());
```

`geocoder.options` is not documented in the API so there's no guarantees about if it'll work or if it will keep working in new releases.